# How specify GBP currency in proc tabulate format

Tags: sas

What is the format for GBP currency?

I would like to have the variable 'rent' to be displayed as £X in the below tabulate. What format should I put in the 'format' statement?

An example would be the equivalent of 'format=dollar12' that gives the USD currency. What would it be for GBP?

```
proc tabulate format=?;
var rent;
class bedrooms city;
table bedrooms, (city=' ' all='Total')*rent=' '*mean=' ' / box='Average Rent';
run;
```

Comment: Could you specify more? You want currency symbol, apply exchange rate or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Apply a format to the mean statistic using `* f= NLMNLGBP.`

From https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/How-do-I-specify-a-currency-format-and-a-comma-format-in-a-DATA/td-p/80230

> applied NLMNLGBP. to the currency field, which formatted it as £1,672,349

**Sample code**

```
data have;
  bedrooms=2; city='London'; rent=4500;
  label rent = 'Rent';
  format rent NLMNLGBP.;
run;

proc tabulate data=have;
class bedrooms city;
var rent;

table 
  bedrooms
  ,
  (city=' ' all='Total')
  * rent=' ' 
    * mean=' ' * f=NLMNLGBP.   %* <----- Happy brexiting ;
  / 
  box='Average Rent'
  ;
run;
```